# iptables forwarding stops working after suspending or rebooting

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, port-forwarding, iptables

I am trying to forward packets received by a PC on port 16080 to port 3389 to another PC connected to it via Ethernet, where `enp1s0` is the Ethernet interface and `10.42.0.66` is the IP of the connected computer.

To achieve that, I run the following commands:

```
$ sudo iptables -I FORWARD -o enp1s0 -d 10.42.0.66 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 16080 -j DNAT --to 10.42.0.66:3389
$ sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 16080 -j DNAT --to 10.42.0.66:3389
```

I then use [iptables-persistent](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/iptables-persistent) and `# iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4` to keep these rules in subsequent boots.

The problem is, the forwarding stops working not only after rebooting the PC, but even after suspending/sleep. What is really mystifying is that the rules appear to actually persist - when I examine the output of `iptables-save`, they are still present.
I only have to run the first command in order for the forwarding to work again.

Here's the output of iptables-save when the forwarding is working:

```
$ sudo iptables-save       
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jun 18 13:10:15 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1258645:1807828971]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1245407:1804789136]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [41:3100]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [903023:597186031]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [904094:597315982]
-A POSTROUTING -o lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
-A POSTROUTING -o lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun 18 13:10:15 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jun 18 13:10:15 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1245375:1804787332]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [903023:597186031]
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.66/32 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -o lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.66/32 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -o lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun 18 13:10:15 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jun 18 13:10:15 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [21385:4652763]
:INPUT ACCEPT [8170:1614588]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [37981:2537586]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [37624:2475722]
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 16080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.42.0.66:3389
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 16080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.42.0.66:3389
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 ! -d 10.0.3.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 ! -d 10.0.3.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun 18 13:10:15 2022
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy-save to see them
```

And when it's not:

```
$ sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jun 18 12:59:09 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1254586:1806558968]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1241553:1803567261]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [41:3100]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [899122:596793155]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [900181:596921700]
-A POSTROUTING -o lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
-A POSTROUTING -o lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun 18 12:59:09 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jun 18 12:59:09 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1241521:1803565457]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [899122:596793155]
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -o lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.66/32 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -o lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun 18 12:59:09 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jun 18 12:59:09 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [21049:4576369]
:INPUT ACCEPT [8039:1586322]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [37198:2487067]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [36849:2426639]
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 16080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.42.0.66:3389
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 16080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.42.0.66:3389
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 ! -d 10.0.3.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 ! -d 10.0.3.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun 18 12:59:09 2022
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy-save to see them
```

Comment: Somehow it looks that running rules are automatically saved. Which is bad when tools dynamically insert their own rule. This behavior should be limited to package upgrade of iptables-persistent (and is already a bad behavior) but in your case it appears it happens very often, leading to all these duplicate rules inserted in front and competing with your own rules.

Comment: Well, I've noticed that some rules are inserted every time the Ethernet connection is established, which explains why suspending also breaks the forwarding... How do I determine which process is adding these rules? Right now I suspect NetworkManager, but I don't know how to find out for sure.

Comment: I found entries like this in `/var/log/syslog`: `NetworkManager[703]: <info>  [1655579699.3559] Executing: /usr/sbin/iptables --table filter --insert FORWARD --in-interface enp1s0 --jump REJECT`. Now to figure out how to stop NetworkManager from doing this...

Comment: It appears these rules are added because I've set NM to share the PC's internet connection to the connected machine. Turning that off is not an option. **Is there a way I can 'sticky' an iptables rule so it's always on top?**

Comment: It's a band-aid, but I removed the offending FORWARD rule from `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` and instead added a script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` which reinserts the rule for every up event for enp1s0 (after deleting the old one, of course). It appears to be working for now.